# How to replace the '.hasChanged' in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

The .hasChanged code is making an error what code should I replace it ?

```
    while (true) {
        if (TextMeshProComponent.hasChanged)
        {
            width = TextMeshProComponent.preferredWidth;
            cloneTextObject.text = TextMeshProComponent.text;
        }

        textRectTransform.position = new Vector3(-scrollPosition % width, startPosition.y, startPosition.z);
        scrollPosition += ScrollSpeed * 20 * Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

[.hasChanged Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsFxv.png)

Comment: Please hover over the error and paste the error message into the question.

Answer (score 0):

This hasChanged property was removed a while ago. This has been replaced by ON_TEXT_CHANGED. Take a look at the example script VertexJitter.cs included in the Examples & Extras/Scripts folder.

For more information check https://forum.unity.com/threads/textmesh-pro-advanced-text-rendering-for-unity-beta-now-available-in-asset-store.227790/page-29